# The set of traces of orthogonal matrices is compact

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness, orthogonal-matrices

> Is the following set compact: $$M = \{ \operatorname{Tr}(A) : A \in M(n,\mathbb R) \text{ is orthogonal}\}$$ where $\operatorname{Tr}(A) $ denotes the trace of $A$?

In order to be compact $M$ has to be closed and bounded.

$\|A\|=\sqrt {\sum_{i,j} {a_{ij}}^2}=\sqrt n $ and hence bounded. So $\operatorname{Tr}(A)<\sqrt n $. Hence $M$ is bounded.

Now we have to prove that $M$ is closed. Let $\operatorname{Tr}(A_n)$ be a sequence of matrices converging to $\operatorname{Tr}(A)$ where $A_n$ is a sequence of orthogonal matrices. The only thing remaining to show is that $A$ is orthogonal.

Comment: Since you were given this question, I would imagine that you're allowed to use the result that the set of orthogonal matrices is compact.

Comment: $A$ is not a set, so $A$ is not compact. The set of orthogonal matrices is compact under the usual topology.

Comment: There's a flaw in your argument. You cannot assume that $A_n \to A$ such that $tr(A_n) \to tr(A)$. In general you have to show that for any sequence of matrices $(A_n)$ such that $\lim tr(A_n) = l$ for some number $l$, then $l = tr(A)$ for some orthogonal matrix $A$. There's a difference.

Comment: It's not true that $\text{Tr}(A) \le \sqrt{n}$.  The correct bound is $n$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Besides using compactness of the set of orthogonal matrices, you can show directly that the set of possible traces is $[-n,n]$.   Note that $I$ and $-I$ are orthogonal with $\text{Tr}(I) = n$ and $\text{Tr}(-I) = -n$.
On the other hand, each matrix element of an orthogonal matrix has absolute value at most $1$, so $\text{Tr}(T) = \sum_{i=1}^n T_{ii}$ has absolute value at most $n$.

To get orthogonal matrices with every trace value from $-n$ to $n$, consider those made from diagonal blocks of the form
$$\pmatrix{\cos \theta & \sin \theta\cr -\sin \theta & \cos\theta}$$
with an additional diagonal entry of $+1$ or $-1$ in case $n$ is odd.

Comment: Sir ,I did not get your last paragraph "to get orthogonal..." for example how to get a $3\times 3$ orthogonal matrix with $\operatorname{Tr A}=0.6 $ say

Comment: it will be great if you could explain

Comment: $\pmatrix{\cos \theta & \sin\theta & 0\cr
              -\sin\theta & \cos\theta & 0\cr
            0 & 0 & 1\cr}$ where $\cos \theta = -0.2$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael This is one of the easiest and clear proofs I have seen.

Answer (score 1):

The orthogonal matrices are compact, as I show below. The trace function is continuous, so the image of the orthogonals under this function must be compact as well.

To see that the orthogonals are compact, first note that the condition $A^TA = I$ is a closed condition. It is the preimage of a single point (closed) under a continuous map, as long as you define the continuous map properly. Further, they are bounded, since their columns are all of norm one.

Comment: Nitpick: having bounded eigenvalues is not sufficient to prove that the matrices themselves are bounded (e.g. transvections).

Comment: is the trace function continuous because every linear map on a finite dimensional space is continuous

Comment: Or because the maps $f_{ij}$ which send $A\mapsto A_{ij}$ are continuous, and the linear combination of them is continuous. @learnmore

Comment: In fact, learnmore shows that the orthogonal matrices are bounded by noting that they all satisfy $\|A\| = \sqrt n$

Comment: @Eric Auld they are bounded because every row/column vector has norm 1

Comment: @D.Thomine Good point. But it does if they are all diagonalizable, right?

Comment: Wrong. Take $((2,t),(0,1))$. If you go this path, you also need to control the angle between the eigenspaces... With the orthogonal matrices, it is easier to compute their norm (see learnmore's comment).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** To show that $A$ is orthogonal, consider $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left\| A_n^TA_n - I \right\|$, noting that the function
$$
f(X) = \left\| X^TX - I \right\|
$$
is continuous.